# Magento static block displaying html instead of element

Tags: html, magento, themes, e-commerce, static-block

Hello my boss bought a theme for magento called megatronics

Now I have followed the manual precisely, somehow I'm having problems with some of the static blocks. They are displaying just plain html code like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9wch.png

I don't know how to fix have googled with every possible tag I could think but no results.

I Would appreciate to have help from you guys thanks

Comment: Can you show some html code that is created?

Comment: <div class="spec_navigation">
<div class="navigation_label">
<img src="http://localhost/magento/skin/frontend/default/MAG090167/images/weekly_special.png" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="navigation_links">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Sony Bravia</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Blackberry Pearl</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Rebel XT 8MP</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Canon EOS 5D</a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="#">Sony Camera</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="all_cate"><span><a href="#">See all</a></span></div>
</div>
 this is the navigation block

Comment: sorry forgoet to link you @Icewind

Comment: It would be important to see the code that is before the code that is not rendered correctly.

Comment: I dont know where to look I followed the manual by going to admin panel => CMS => Static blocks => and then added a new block where i need to put the values for block title, identifier and for content i need to put the html code which i did as said in the manual... i dont know where it loads the code @Icewind

Comment: http://pastebin.com/G4ghuGw4 @Icewind this is cms.xml code from the magento folder

Answer (score 2):

nevermind I put the theme html code in the wrong WYSIWYG view and ended with  being replaced by htmlspecialchars code and thats why it did display html code =)